# Apache Reverse Proxy For Specific Subdomain

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I'm have a an Apache HTTP server that has a reverse proxy to a tomcat server. However, I only want the reverse proxy to happen when the client uses the subdomain www. This is because I want to use other subdomains to point to other applications, such as email.

e.g. www.example.com will go display the apache tomcat webapp.

The way to do this, I presume, is to configure my DNS so that every subdomain I use will point to my server. Right now, in addition to www, that is server.example.com and posfixadmin.example.com. However, the issue is that all my subdomains end up pointing to tomcat.

So when I try to visit postfixadmin.example.com/setup.php to set up postfixadmin through its web setup, it ends up taking me to my tomcat webapp's 404.

Here is my virtualhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost www.example.com:80>
    ServerName http://www.example.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080
</Virtualhost>

<VirtualHost server.example.com:80>
    ServerName server.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =server.example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} {END,NE,R=permanent}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost postfixadmin.example.com:80>
    ServerName postfixadmin.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/postfixadmin/public

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/postfixadmin_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/postfixadmin_access.log combined

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/postfixadmin/public>
       Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT**
It looks like the proxy conf file doesn't do anything (??). I decided to experiment around and change the first virtualhost servername to the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abcd.example.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080
</Virtualhost>
```

Then, I restarted and reloaded Apache...But for some reason, going to www.example.com STILL took me to the tomcat webapp! Does anyone know what drives this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

It turns out that the problem was in the ssl configuration file - the :443 ports were overlapping.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As to the DNS: I have set specific CNAME entries for each subdomain including www; all of them point back to the public IP of my server that houses my example.com domain (using @ in my case - possible with most DNS, I think). There may be some different strategies on this, but I believe you're on the correct path based on what you've suggested in the question.

As to Apache configuration:
I believe that the `http` protocol does not need to be specified in the `ServerName` directive and that, generally, the domain need not appear inside the `<VirtualHost>`...`</VirtualHost>` tags.

I should mention that I am relatively unfamiliar with Tomcat but am assuming it is listening at 8080 on the localhost, in which case this should help.

I'm not 100% certain that that is all that is snarling you, but try trimming that `ServerName` back and doing like so, including the change to the `VirtualHost` open tag:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080
</Virtualhost>
```

Your second `<VirtualHost>` probably requires similar changes, though it also seems that you are directing it to serve requests from the web/network ***which are coming in on port 8080*** -- which I don't believe is your intent.

I think what you want is to also listen on ***port 80*** from the web/network, but to follow these directives if addressed to `server.example.com` like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =server.example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} {END,NE,R=permanent}
</VirtualHost>
```

And finally, similar change to the opening `<VirtualHost>` tag on the final one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName postfixadmin.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/postfixadmin/public

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/postfixadmin_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/postfixadmin_access.log combined

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/postfixadmin/public>
       Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

***Altogether, this seems more like what you're looking for:***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080
</Virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =server.example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} {END,NE,R=permanent}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName postfixadmin.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/postfixadmin/public

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/postfixadmin_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/postfixadmin_access.log combined

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/postfixadmin/public>
       Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
The 8080 thing was a typo in the post but not in my config file, thank you for pointing that out. However, the change did not seem to make a difference for me.
Also, I am using A records, not CNAME records, to point to my IP address. Each of my subdomains points to the server IP, however the naked domain does not. Should it?

Comment: I could not comment on your self-answer below, but glad to hear that you got it! I may have been incorrect in saying it was a CNAME, to be honest; I always reverse those and that's the one thing I did not look up in composing my answer. But all of mine do point to the server IP in my case, as well. (My particular install has the config spread across multiple .conf files so I can totally appreciate your predicament there as most instructions I see online point to solutions that don't exactly fit my install!)